# Firefox search results not showing favicon

Tags: firefox, browser, avast, favicon, malwarebytes

[image: Example when I search "youtube"]

So I recently downloaded Avast One and cleared my browser caches, but now when I search for things on Firefox all of the favicons are weird circles, some of which are weirdly colored. Not sure what to do?

I also activated Malwarebytes Browser Guard, but I think that was after this showed up. This all happened in the span of 20 minutes.

Comment: You could save your Firefox data (even save all of the profile folder) and reinstall Firefox.